# Dice rolling program in PHP

Tags: php, html

I made a simple program where the user has to guess the value rolled by a virtual dice.

Here's the HTML and the PHP:

```
<body>
<h2 id="heading"> We're gonna roll a dice! <br><small>And you have to guess which number the dice will roll.</small></h2>
<form action="" method="post">
<div id="test-container">
    <p>Select your guess: </p>
    <select class="form-control" id="select" name="dice">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<button id="submit" type="submit" type="button" name="roll" class="btn btn-primary">Roll!</button>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['roll']))
{
$dice = $_POST['dice'];
$rand = rand(1,6);
if($dice == $rand)
{
    echo "<br>" . "your guess is correct! The number rolled by the dice was " . $rand . "!";
}
else{
    echo "<br>" . "your guess is wrong! The number rolled by the dice was " . $rand . " but the number you entered was " . $dice . "!";
}

}

?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code itself works, but that's not the issue. **When I press submit, I want the following gif (positioned in-between the button and the echoed output) to appear, and play just once without looping**:

[image: I want it to be in-between the button and the echoed output]

I've tried many ways to do this, but none of them seem to work!

I understand that I require an image editor to prevent it from looping forever. As for displaying it, the syntax is `echo "<img src='handroll.gif'>"`, as I just found out.

Comment: Edit the GIF in an image editing software and make the GIF non-loopable. Since you reload the page on each submit, it should work as intended.

Comment: Could you recommend a good image editing software to do this? @alesc

Comment: You can place image in your HTML, hide it with CSS and when form is submitted (you have on-submit event) you can un-hide it. Only thing I'm not sure is will animation will be already finished when image appears. If so, then you'll have to add image dynamically to your HTML, with JavaScript.

Comment: Try something from this [list](http://www.freewaregenius.com/remove-endless-loops-gif/). I personally only know GIMP, so I would recommend it.

Comment: There is a Microsoft Gif Animator...free tool for editing gifs. But of course PhotoShop can do it.

Comment: @alesc could you check out my edit?

Comment: in your edit, notice that the way you handle your quotation marks is incorrect (you end your string before `handroll.gif`. So you either need to escape the inner quotes: ` \" ` or replace either pair with single quotes.

Comment: The hand throws with two dice, but the dropdown can only handle one die.

Comment: @Ja͢ck I can't find a better gif ;~;

Comment: @Burki I tried your suggestion, and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the value of $_POST[roll] to null after rolling the dice. As I see it, the the value remains true always once the button is clicked and you are not "re-initializing" it per se.

```
if(isset($_POST['roll'])) {
// all that you need to do

// as the last line or something like this
$_POST['roll'] = null;
}
```

Because, normally when you submit a form, the form data or submit status gets reset and so does the session value.

If the above doesn't work, you can also try a form/input type=submit setup. It's easier to drive button clicks through jquery/js.

Comment: This answer didn't really work, I actually got the answer in the comments section. But whatever, have the upvotes Cx

Comment: In that case, please add the answer and mark that as the correct one because this can become misleading to others who might waste time trying that approach. Thanks for the points but I would have written it as a comment myself if i had enough credit. I didn't really intend it as an answer but as a suggestion.